# How to gather Member of details of a Active Directory user account

Tags: c#, winforms

Kindly let me know how to gather Member of details of a user account in Active directory. See image below. I am using windows form App (c#). Also when gathering the data it shouldn't give nested group name as well. I need to gather exactly the groups are showing in Member of section in user properties.

[image]

I tried below function. It gives output as i expected but only on few users. Most of the users gives an error.

**function I tried**

```
public List<string> GetUserImmediateGroups(string userName)
{
    List<string> groupNames = new List<string>();

    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);

        if (user != null)
        {
            // Get the immediate groups that the user is a member of
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> userGroups = user.GetGroups();

            foreach (GroupPrincipal group in userGroups.OfType<GroupPrincipal>())
            {
                groupNames.Add(group.SamAccountName);
            }
        }

        return groupNames; // Return the list of immediate group names
    }
}
```

**But sometimes gives an error**

`Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355).`

Comment: Which user do you use to access the AD? Maybe the user doesnt have the rights to check other DC?

Comment: Hi Aaron, The application is running on a Domain enrolled workstation which also logged in with a Domain Admin Account. It have relevant permissions and rather than this I used few more functions to collect AD data and they are getting the data without an error.

Comment: This function works for me, as written, for my AD account and all my groups. I just had to add `using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;`